# How to batch convert "File" type files to "text" type files

Tags: python

I have many "File" type files. I want to convert them into "Text" files.

Screenshot of files is given below:

I want to convert these files into "Text" files. My code is given below:

```
    os.chdir('FolderName/')
    extension = 'txt'
    raw_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*')]   ### len(all_filenames1)
    text_filenames = ['%s'%(i).format(extension) for i in raw_filenames]
    print(len(text_filenames))
    print(type(raw_filenames[0]))
    print(type(text_filenames[0]))
```

Output:

```
    108
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'str'>
```

Above code is running successfully but not converting the files to `.txt` format. 
I am trying to do two things:

1. How to convert these file into `txt` format and
2. save them with same name back to same folder?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. So far it sounds as if you have a bunch of files w/o extension and you want to rename them from ``filename`` to ``filename.txt``, is that correct? It would help if you include an example in your quesion, showing what you've got and also showing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hey! What OS are you on? Unix tends to not care about extensions and windows only uses extensions to determine how to handle the data inside.

Comment: `text_filenames` should be crested as `['{}.{}'.format(file, extension) for file in raw_filenames]`

Comment: @MikeScotty I have 108 files in `File` format. I can open a file of 108 files in Notepad and save as `.txt` file. I cannot do 108 files manually. Instead, Now I want to save all files in `.txt` format using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little example to rename recursively files using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) combo:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import sys

basedir = Path("FolderName").resolve(strict=True)
print(f"Renaming files in {basedir}")

prefix = "\\\\?\\" if sys.platform == "win32" else ""

for src in basedir.glob("**/*"):
    if src.is_dir():
        continue

    dst = src.with_suffix('.txt')
    if not dst.exists():
        try:
            os.rename(f"{prefix}{src}", f"{prefix}{dst}")
            print(f"Renamed {src}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error renaming: {e}")
```

On Windows, if dst exists a FileExistsError is always raised, that's why you should check if dst already exists. Also, it may happen that because some paths being too long os.rename could raise a `[WinError 3]` exception, that's why using the prefix "\?\".

For more info about `[WinError 3]` you can check the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation

Answer (score 1):

I think renaming would work. Check the following code

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir('FolderName/')
extension = 'txt'
raw_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*')]   ### len(all_filenames1)
text_filenames = ['%s'%(i).format(extension) for i in raw_filenames]
print(len(text_filenames))
print(type(raw_filenames[0]))
print(type(text_filenames[0]))

for in, out in zip(raw_filename, text_filenames)
    os.rename(in, out)
```

Comment: ``['%s'%(i).format(extension) for i in raw_filenames]`` will do nothing, unless the raw filename already includes the characters ``{}``. You could use ``text_filenames = ['{}.{}'.format(i, extension) for i in raw_filenames]`` however.

Comment: @ivallesp I tried your method. Got following error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:`

Comment: True Mike, I didn't check it. I think you have to follow also Mike's advice, Mainland, you are not creating the "text_filenames" correctly

Comment: @MikeScotty I tried your method. It ran without errors. I tried this to confirm that conversion happened `print(text_filenames[0])`. It returned following output `file1.txt` but not the file contents. Moreover, I could not save it back to the folder using above code.