# Convert a skeleton file to csv with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataset

My college teacher gave me a task to take from a dataset called the ntu dataset some specific skeleton files copy them to a new folder and then convert them to csv ones.I cant find a way to make it work.Right now the code below gives me an error:

** line 75, in 
os.rename(os.path.join(path, file),
ValueError: rename: dst too long for Windows **

```
import os,shutil
import os.path
from os import path
import csv
from pathlib import Path

fileNamesF = []

#Path of skeleton files && Path of the new skeleton.csv files
original_skeleton_location = 'C:\\Users\\Apostolos\\Documents\\Programming Folders\\Ptixiaki\\skeletons\\nturgbS01-17-skeletons'
base_directory = 'C:\\Users\\Apostolos\\Documents\\Programming Folders\\Ptixiaki\\skeletons\\csvSkeletons'

#Check and create path for the new csv files 
if  not os.path.exists('C:\\Users\\Apostolos\\Documents\\Programming Folders\\Ptixiaki\\skeletons\\csvSkeletons'):
    os.mkdir(base_directory)

#Check and create path for healthAction files
healthActions_directory = os.path.join(base_directory,'healthActions')
if not os.path.exists(healthActions_directory):
    os.mkdir(healthActions_directory)

#copy files to healthActions directory
def copyFiles():
    for fileName in fileNames:
        try:
            source = os.path.join(original_skeleton_location, fileName)
            dest = os.path.join(healthActions_directory, fileName)
            shutil.copyfile(source, dest)
        except OSError:
            pass

#copy skeleton files to a new destination
fileNames = ['S00{}C00{}P00{}R00{}A0{}.skeleton'.format(s,c,p,r,a)
    for s in range(1,10,2)
    for c in range(1,4)
    for p in range(1,9)
    for r in range(1,3) 
    for a in range(41,50)]
fileNamesF.append(fileNames)
copyFiles()

fileNames = ['S0{}C00{}P00{}R00{}A0{}.skeleton'.format(s, c, p, r, a)
             for s in range(11,18, 2)
             for c in range(1, 4)
             for p in range(1, 9)
             for r in range(1, 3)
             for a in range(41, 50)]
fileNamesF.append(fileNames)
copyFiles()

fileNames = ['S00{}C00{}P0{}R00{}A0{}.skeleton'.format(s, c, p, r, a)
             for s in range(1, 10, 2)
             for c in range(1, 4)
             for p in range(10, 40)
             for r in range(1, 3)
             for a in range(41, 50)]
fileNamesF.append(fileNames)
copyFiles()

fileNames = ['S0{}C00{}P0{}R00{}A0{}.skeleton'.format(s, c, p, r, a)
             for s in range(11, 18, 2)
             for c in range(1, 4)
             for p in range(10,40)
             for r in range(1, 3)
             for a in range(41, 50)]
fileNamesF.append(fileNames)
copyFiles()


path = healthActions_directory
files = os.listdir(path)

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    for i in range(len(fileNamesF)):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, file),
        os.path.join(path, ''.join([str(fileNamesF[i]), '.csv'])))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maximum-path-length-limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479244/how-to-batch-convert-file-type-files-to-text-type-files)

Comment: Thank you very much!It worked!